# batch tool for sending files over webdav

Tags: linux, shell-script, webdav

I know there is cadaver for working with webdav. But it opens an interactive console. I want to write a script that will send files over webdav protocol in a batch mode. What tool can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cURL:

```
curl -T filetoput.xml http://www.url.com/
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205101/command-line-utility-for-webdav-upload